# Configuring Dapper.Extensions.Linq

Tags: c#, f#

Can someone help me on how to configure Dapper.Extensions.Linq (https://github.com/ryanwatson/Dapper.Extensions.Linq) for the first time.

I have been trying to set it up for a F# project, though it's hard to grasp from the readme (https://github.com/ryanwatson/Dapper.Extensions.Linq#configuration).

Comment: Have you looked at type providers? You could use a type provider in F# and the same functionality *and* compile-time type safety and intellisense. No configuration, mappings or DTOs needed, just a single connection string is enough. Check [Walkthroug: Accessing a database using type providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/walkthrough-accessing-a-sql-database-by-using-type-providers-%5Bfsharp%5D)

Comment: To put it another way, is there any reason you *aren't* using type providers?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Our model is historically designed to have 20-30 properties. So we were looking for some orm, which have support for all features of CRUD. I'm not able to find suitable update method in sql provder.
eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906550/how-to-put-the-u-in-f-type-provider-crud

Comment: First, some type providers work with LINQ so you don't need an ORM to map 30 fields. Check eg [SQLProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/) which supports both LINQ and CRUD. Second, the only place where you'd need 30 properties at once is for a (very wide) grid or report - the very scenario where ORMs are a no-no. A proper SELECT, a view or a LINQ query would be preferable. Since you are already looking at Dapper you've already decided to go that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much a direct translation of the C# settings.

```
open Dapper.Extensions.Linq.Core.Configuration
open Dapper.Extensions.Linq.Mapper
open Dapper.Extensions.Linq.Sql
open Dapper.Extensions.Linq.CastleWindsor

DapperConfiguration.Use()
                   .UseClassMapper(typeof<AutoClassMapper<_>>)
                   .UseContainer<Dapper.Extensions.Linq.CastleWindsor.ContainerForWindsor>(fun c ->  c.UseExisting(_container))
                   .UseSqlDialect(new SqlServerDialect())
                   .FromAssembly("Dapper.Entities")
                   .Build()
```

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 5.0 C#, I've added this line in Startup.ConfigureServices and it worked:

```
DapperConfiguration.Use()
               .UseClassMapper(typeof(CustomTableMapper<>))
               .UseContainer<ContainerForWindsor>(c => c.UseExisting(new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer()))
               .UseSqlDialect(new PostgreSqlDialect())
               .Build();
```